# Regex: Retrieve number after repeated string

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have a string:

```
\foo\junk\f0\morejunk\
```

How can I extract 'f0' from it using regex?  I essentially only want to match an 'f' followed by a number, without it getting caught on strings beginning with 'f' not followed by a number.

I have tried the following:

```
(?<=f)(\d*)
```

But this gets stuck on the first 'f' in the string, 'foo' and doesn't match the latter case of 'f0'.  How can I put a quantifier on a `lookbehind` to match the string I want?

another option could be to split the string by the '\' delimiter and try to match each split, but this seems unnecessary?

Comment: Ah I was using the wrong quantifier, thank you for pointing out my stupidity

Comment: Not just _quantifier_, complete regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look behind is not supported in JavaScript regex. You can use capture group. Also use `+` instead of `*`, since `*` matches `0` or more characters while `+` will match one or more of the preceding character.

```js
var str='\\foo\\junk\\f0\\morejunk\\';
var res=str.match(/\\f(\d+)\\/)[1];
alert(res);
```

**Update :** If you want to match entire string then just use `/f\d+/` no need of capturing group

```js
var str='\\foo\\junk\\f0\\morejunk\\';
var res=str.match(/\\(f\d+)\\/)[1];
alert(res);
```

Comment: Thank you for your explination

Comment: _"How can I extract 'f0' from it using regex?"_, use `/(f\d+)/`.

Comment: `match(/f\d+/)[0]`  for extracting entire string

Comment: This one is wrong. Such pattern will match any string like \foo\junk\junkf0junk\morejunk\. My solution posted below/above.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
/(f\d+)/
```

It matches `f` followed by one or more digits. The result is in group 1.

Comment: Apply this pattern for \foo\junk\junkf0junk\morejunk\

Comment: @MaxZuber: well, it gives `f0`, so what?

Comment: According the last paragraph of the question, it should be `junkf0junk` and it doesn't match the pattern then

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = '\\foo\\junk\\f0\\morejunk\\';
var expression = /\\(f(\d+))\\/;
var matches_array = string.match(expression);
```